# UV warp modifier seems dependent on object origin; posing a rigged model with a UV warp eye setup is thus problematic

Tags: modifiers, uv, armature

As the title says. Origin for the "From" object carrying the modifier and relevant eye textures is set to center of mass (surface), and the origin of the "To" controller bone is set to that location as well—setting one of the armature's bones as the To has the same issue, and also does as illustrated in the final pic, requiring tweaking of the Transform settings and even then it's still slightly off-kilter no matter what.

Setting the origin of the "From" to correspond with that of the rest of the model + its armature creates another issue entirely, where it just doesn't seem to register the location of the "To" at all.

Using the latest release version, only external addon present is Retopoflow fwiw.

[image]
The bone in front is the "To" object, and the facial texture with the eyes is the "From" object

[image]
Works fine when it's just the "To" being moved, but the eye texture distorts and rotates when the underlying armature, specifically the bones responsible for deforming the "From", is manipulated. The "To" bone is simply parented via modifier.

[image]
ditto

[image]
Eye node setup

[image]
Modifier

[image]

I hope there's a simple explanation for this that I'm just missing. One possible issue is texture coordinates, but there's no place to plug that in.

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Experimentation has provided a tentative solution: giving the eye mesh its own armature, parented to the head of the primary one.

The *To* still needs to be yet another separate object, though, else the warping highlighted in the last example still occurs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.